# How does one calculate the minimum spectral linewidth in cm$^{-1}$ of a pulsed laser with pulse duration of 10 fs?

Tags: laser, fourier-transform

I calculated the minimum spectral linewidth given here using the uncertainty principle that $\Delta E\,\Delta t =h/2\pi$.
Will this be correct?

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between line width and time is given by the Fourier transform of the pulse shape. A 10 fs pulse has a "length" of $c\cdot \Delta t$, and a line width that is the inverse of that. With some scaling factor depending on how you define line width. A bit of manipulation will show this is the same as the answer you got.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon the shape of your laser pulse. The time bandwidth product is defined as:

$$\Delta v \Delta t \geqslant K $$

Where both $\Delta v$ and $\Delta t$ are measured as FWHM (full width half max). The factor $K$ depends upon the shape of your laser pulse. 
$K = 0.441$ for a Gaussian shaped pulse,
$0.315$ for a sech pulse,
$0.142$ for a Lorentzian pulse.

If you only have your spectral width given in terms of $\lambda$ (nm) i.e. you have $\Delta \lambda$ (nm) then the time bandwidth product can be expressed as:

$$ \Delta t \geqslant K \frac {\lambda_{0}^{2}}{\Delta \lambda c}$$
Where $\Delta \lambda$ is again measured using FWHM.